# Deserialize json message - Performance Considerations

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have big JSON message that I get from HttpClient GetAsync as a stream.
The returned JSON is an array of objects.

I need to parse only one attribute from the first JSON object, and one attribute from the last JSON object. What will be the best way to do it performance wise?

I use Newtonsoft JSON.

**I don't want to parse the whole JSON string, just parse specific attributes.**

Comment: any performance issue?

Comment: Yes. Those messages are large, and we need to handle multiple of them in short amount of time.

Comment: how about Regex?

Comment: Have you tried looping through the stream and parsing only attributes that you're interested in? Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43747641/7912895