# Extract first element from JSON

Tags: c#, json

How can I take just the first element from a Json?

```
//take result back
    void HandleIncomingMessage(object sender, PEventArgs e)
    {
        RetMessage += e.Result;
        //here can not deserialize correct
        var deserialized_message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(RetMessage);
    }
```

Here I am doing the deserialize but because it`s taking the entire object can not parse it correct.

I need just JSON.[0]

[image]

Edit: Raw Json :

```
 [{"unique_id":55,"action_name":"INSERT","start_date":"2018-06-11T16:00:00","end_date":"2018-06-11T17:00:00"},"1sddsd","my_channel"]
```

Comment: `JSON[0]`.....?

Comment: Show the raw json...

Comment: This question would be greatly improved if you posted the raw JSON string and not an image of the debug pane.

Comment: I need just unique_id, action_name, start_date and end_date

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse huge JSON file as stream in Json.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747477/how-to-parse-huge-json-file-as-stream-in-json-net)

Comment: I know the duplicate isn't identical to your problem, but it shows how you can read JSON gradually rather than all at once.

Comment: Since your json is unstructured, you need to use dynamic parsing, parse it into a `JArray`, then grab the first element and deserialize that to your `Message` type.

Comment: This should work: `JArray.Parse(json)[0].ToObject<Message>()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Deserialize to `List<dynamic>`, then read the properties of its first element.

```
//using Newtonsoft.Json;
var input = @"[{""unique_id"":55,""action_name"":""INSERT"",""start_date"":""2018-06-11T16:00:00"",""end_date"":""2018-06-11T17:00:00""},""1sddsd"",""my_channel""]";
var output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(input);
Console.WriteLine(output[0].unique_id);
```

Output:

55

[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SU6vD2)

Comment: You are right, this helps me to deserialize it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about getting json string and using [JSON.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

```
//first create object from json
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
//read unique value        
string jUniqueId = jObject["unique_id"];
//or
string firstObject = jObject[0];
```

Comment: You mean `JArray.Parse`.

Comment: No, IT IS `JObject.Parse` of `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq`

Answer (score -3):

the solution is for static,

```
JObject obj= JObject.Parse(here pass the JSON);
  string id=  JSON[0]["unique_id"],
  string name=  JSON[0]["action_name"],
  string sdate=  JSON[0]["start_date"],
  string edate=  JSON[0]["end_date"]
```

dynamic means pass **i** instead of 0.

Comment: Reason for downvote: What is `JSON`? Where does `JSON` come from?

Comment: You now have the same issue as aditya.