# Asynchonously deserializing a list using System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.0, c#-8.0, system.text.json

Lets say that I request a large json file that contains a list of many objects. I don't want them to be in memory all at once, but I would rather read and process them one by one. So I need to turn an async `System.IO.Stream` stream into an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`. How do I use the new `System.Text.Json` API to do this?

```
private async IAsyncEnumerable<T> GetList<T>(Uri url, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    using (var httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(url, cancellationToken))
    {
        using (var stream = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        {
            // Probably do something with JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync here without serializing the entire thing in one go
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll probably need something like [DeserializeAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserializeasync?view=netcore-3.0) method

Comment: Sorry, it seems that method above loads the entire stream into the memory. You can read the data by chunks asynchonously using `Utf8JsonReader`, please have a look at some github [samples](https://github.com/scalablecory/system-text-json-samples/blob/master/json-test/JsonParser.ParseSimpleAsync.cs) and at existing [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54983533/parsing-a-json-file-with-net-core-3-0-system-text-json) as well

Comment: `GetAsync` by itself returns when the *entire* response is received. You need to use `SendAsync` with ` HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead` instead. Once you have that you can use JSON.NET's [JsonTextReader](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextReader.htm). Using `System.Text.Json` for this isn't that easy [as this issue shows](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/39655). The functionality isn't available and implementing it in a low-allocation using structs isn't trivial

Comment: The problem with deserializing in chunks is that you have to know when you have a complete chunk to deserialize. This would be difficult to cleanly accomplish for general cases. It would require parsing in advance, which could be quite a poor tradeoff in terms of performance. It would rather difficult to generalize. But if you enforce your own restrictions on your JSON, say "a single object occupies exactly 20 lines in the file", then you could essentially deserialize asynchronously by reading the file in chunks async. You would need a massive json to see benefit here though, I would imagine.

Comment: Looks like someone already answered a *similar* question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54983533/parsing-a-json-file-with-net-core-3-0-system-text-json) with full code.

Comment: Are you looking for something not covered in the related question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, a truly streaming JSON (de)serializer would be a nice performance improvement to have, in so many places.

Unfortunately, `System.Text.Json` does not do this at the time I'm writing this. I'm not sure if it will in the future - I hope so! Truly streaming deserialization of JSON turns out to be rather challenging.

You could check if the extremely fast [Utf8Json](https://github.com/neuecc/Utf8Json) supports it, perhaps.

However, there might be a custom solution for your specific situation, since your requirements seem to constrain the difficulty.

The idea is to manually read one item from the array at a time. We are making use of the fact that each item in the list is, in itself, a valid JSON object.

You can manually skip past the `[` (for the first item) or the `,` (for each next item). Then I think your best bet is to use .NET Core's `Utf8JsonReader` to determine where the current object ends, and feed the scanned bytes to `JsonDeserializer`.

This way, you're only buffering slightly over one object at a time.

And since we're talking performance, you could get the input from a `PipeReader`, while you're at it. :-)

Comment: This isn't about  performance at all. It's not about async deserialization, which it *already* does. It's about streaming access - processing JSON elements as they are parsed from the stream, the way JSON.NET's JsonTextReader does.

Comment: The relevant class in Utf8Json is JsonReader and as the author says, it's weird. JSON.NET's JsonTextReader and System.Text.Json's Utf8JsonReader share the same weirdness - you have to loop and check the current element's type as you go.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ah, yes, streaming. That's the word I was looking for! I'm updating the word "asynchronous" to "streaming". I do believe the reason to want streaming is limiting memory usage, which is a performance concern. Perhaps OP can confirm.

Comment: Performance doesn't mean speed. No matter how fast the deserializer is, if you have to process 1M items, you *don't* want to store them in RAM, nor wait for all of them to get deserialized before you can process the first one.

Comment: Semantics, my friend! I’m glad we’re trying to achieve the same thing after all.

Answer (score 17):

**TL;DR** It's not trivial

---

Looks like someone *already* [posted full code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55429664/134204) for a `Utf8JsonStreamReader` struct that reads buffers from a stream and feeds them to a Utf8JsonRreader, allowing easy deserialization with `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(ref newJsonReader, options);`. The code isn't trivial either. The related question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54983533/parsing-a-json-file-with-net-core-3-0-system-text-json) and the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55429664/134204).

That's not enough though - `HttpClient.GetAsync` will return only after the entire response is received, essentially buffering everything in memory.

To avoid this, [HttpClient.GetAsync(string,HttpCompletionOption )](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getasync?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Http_HttpClient_GetAsync_System_String_System_Net_Http_HttpCompletionOption_) should be used with `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`.

The deserialization loop should check the cancellation token too, and either exit or throw if it's signalled. Otherwise the loop will go on until the entire stream is received and processed.

This code is based in the related answer's example and uses `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` and checks the cancellation token. It can parse JSON strings that contain a proper array of items, eg :

```
[{"prop1":123},{"prop1":234}]
```

The first call to `jsonStreamReader.Read()` moves to the start of the array while the second moves to the start of the first object. The loop itself terminates when the end of the array (`]`) is detected.

```
private async IAsyncEnumerable<T> GetList<T>(Uri url, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    //Don't cache the entire response
    using var httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(url,                               
                                                       HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead,  
                                                       cancellationToken);
    using var stream = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    using var jsonStreamReader = new Utf8JsonStreamReader(stream, 32 * 1024);

    jsonStreamReader.Read(); // move to array start
    jsonStreamReader.Read(); // move to start of the object

    while (jsonStreamReader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.EndArray)
    {
        //Gracefully return if cancellation is requested.
        //Could be cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
        if(cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            return;
        }

        // deserialize object
        var obj = jsonStreamReader.Deserialize<T>();
        yield return obj;

        // JsonSerializer.Deserialize ends on last token of the object parsed,
        // move to the first token of next object
        jsonStreamReader.Read();
    }
}
```

**JSON fragments, AKA streaming JSON aka ...***

It's quite common in event streaming or logging scenarios to append individual JSON objects to a file, one element per line eg :

```
{"eventId":1}
{"eventId":2}
...
{"eventId":1234567}
```

This isn't a valid JSON *document* but the individual fragments are valid. This has several advantages for big data/highly concurrent scenarios. Adding a new event only requires appending a new line to the file, not parsing and rebuilding the entire file. *Processing*, especially *parallel* processing is easier for two reasons:

- Individual elements can be retrieved one at a time, simply by reading one line from a stream.
- The input file can be easily partitioned and split across line boundaries, feeding each part to a separate worker process, eg in a Hadoop cluster, or simply different threads in an application: Calculate the split points eg by dividing the length by the number of workers, then look for the first newline. Feed everything up to that point to a separate worker.

**Using a StreamReader**

The allocate-y way to do this would be to use a TextReader, read one line at a time and parse it with [JsonSerializer.Deserialize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserialize?view=netcore-3.0#System_Text_Json_JsonSerializer_Deserialize__1_System_String_System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_) :

```
using var reader=new StreamReader(stream);
string line;
//ReadLineAsync() doesn't accept a CancellationToken 
while((line=await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
{
    var item=JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(line);
    yield return item;

    if(cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

That's a lot simpler than the code that deserializes a proper array. There are two issues :

- `ReadLineAsync` doesn't accept a cancellation token
- Each iteration allocates a new string, one of the things we wanted to *avoid* by using System.Text.Json

*This may be enough though* as trying to produce the `ReadOnlySpan<Byte>` buffers needed by JsonSerializer.Deserialize isn't trivial.

**Pipelines and SequenceReader**

To avoid alllocations, we need to get a `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` from the stream. Doing this requires using System.IO.Pipeline pipes and the [SequenceReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.sequencereader-1?view=netcore-3.0) struct. Steve Gordon's [An Introduction to SequenceReader](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/an-introduction-to-sequencereader) explains how this class can be used to read data from a stream using delimiters.

Unfortunately, `SequenceReader` is a ref struct which means it can't be used in async or local methods. That's why Steve Gordon in his article creates a

```
private static SequencePosition ReadItems(in ReadOnlySequence<byte> sequence, bool isCompleted)
```

method to read items form a ReadOnlySequence and return the ending position, so the PipeReader can resume from it. *Unfortunately* we want to return an IEnumerable or IAsyncEnumerable, and iterator methods don't like `in` or `out` parameters either.

We could collect the deserialized items in a List or Queue and return them as a single result, but that would still allocate lists, buffers or nodes and have to wait for all items in a buffer to be deserialized before returning :

```
private static (SequencePosition,List<T>) ReadItems(in ReadOnlySequence<byte> sequence, bool isCompleted)
```

We need *something* that acts like an enumerable without requiring an iterator method, works with async and doesn't buffer everything the way.

**Adding Channels to produce an IAsyncEnumerable**

[ChannelReader.ReadAllAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1.readallasync?view=netcore-3.0) returns an IAsyncEnumerable. We can return a ChannelReader from methods that couldn't work as iterators and still produce a stream of elements without caching.

Adapting Steve Gordon's code to use channels, we get the ReadItems(ChannelWriter...) and `ReadLastItem` methods. The first one, reads one item at a time, up to a newline using `ReadOnlySpan<byte> itemBytes`. This can be used by `JsonSerializer.Deserialize`. If `ReadItems` can't find the delimiter, it returns its position so the PipelineReader can pull the next chunk from the stream.

When we reach the last chunk and there's no other delimiter, ReadLastItem` reads the remaining bytes and deserializes them.

The code is almost identical to Steve Gordon's. Instead of writing to the Console, we write to the ChannelWriter.

```
private const byte NL=(byte)'\n';
private const int MaxStackLength = 128;

private static SequencePosition ReadItems<T>(ChannelWriter<T> writer, in ReadOnlySequence<byte> sequence, 
                          bool isCompleted, CancellationToken token)
{
    var reader = new SequenceReader<byte>(sequence);

    while (!reader.End && !token.IsCancellationRequested) // loop until we've read the entire sequence
    {
        if (reader.TryReadTo(out ReadOnlySpan<byte> itemBytes, NL, advancePastDelimiter: true)) // we have an item to handle
        {
            var item=JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(itemBytes);
            writer.TryWrite(item);            
        }
        else if (isCompleted) // read last item which has no final delimiter
        {
            var item = ReadLastItem<T>(sequence.Slice(reader.Position));
            writer.TryWrite(item);
            reader.Advance(sequence.Length); // advance reader to the end
        }
        else // no more items in this sequence
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return reader.Position;
}

private static T ReadLastItem<T>(in ReadOnlySequence<byte> sequence)
{
    var length = (int)sequence.Length;

    if (length < MaxStackLength) // if the item is small enough we'll stack allocate the buffer
    {
        Span<byte> byteBuffer = stackalloc byte[length];
        sequence.CopyTo(byteBuffer);
        var item=JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(byteBuffer);
        return item;        
    }
    else // otherwise we'll rent an array to use as the buffer
    {
        var byteBuffer = ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Rent(length);

        try
        {
            sequence.CopyTo(byteBuffer);
            var item=JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(byteBuffer);
            return item;
        }
        finally
        {
            ArrayPool<byte>.Shared.Return(byteBuffer);
        }

    }    
}
```

The `DeserializeToChannel<T>` method creates a Pipeline reader on top of the stream, creates a channel and starts a worker task that parses chunks and pushes them to the channel :

```
ChannelReader<T> DeserializeToChannel<T>(Stream stream, CancellationToken token)
{
    var pipeReader = PipeReader.Create(stream);    
    var channel=Channel.CreateUnbounded<T>();
    var writer=channel.Writer;
    _ = Task.Run(async ()=>{
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var result = await pipeReader.ReadAsync(token); // read from the pipe

            var buffer = result.Buffer;

            var position = ReadItems(writer,buffer, result.IsCompleted,token); // read complete items from the current buffer

            if (result.IsCompleted) 
                break; // exit if we've read everything from the pipe

            pipeReader.AdvanceTo(position, buffer.End); //advance our position in the pipe
        }

        pipeReader.Complete(); 
    },token)
    .ContinueWith(t=>{
        pipeReader.Complete();
        writer.TryComplete(t.Exception);
    });

    return channel.Reader;
}
```

`ChannelReader.ReceiveAllAsync()` can be used to consume all items through an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`:

```
var reader=DeserializeToChannel<MyEvent>(stream,cts.Token);
await foreach(var item in reader.ReadAllAsync(cts.Token))
{
    //Do something with it 
}
```

Comment: You've missed one thing unless I am mistaken. Utf8JsonStreamReader is a ref struct and thusly cannot be used within an async method. I see you've referenced this issue in other circumstances, but not regarding that initial example.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, @PanagiotisKanavos (and your deleted answer has been also helpful!). Surprising how JSON streaming is still so difficult with `System.Text.Json`. AFAICT, the new `DeserializeAsyncEnumerable` doesn't yet provide a viable solution for infinite streaming of JSON over a socked or a named pipe. It still tries to read the input stream to the end and won't produce any items until the end of the stream.

Comment: I get "CS4012 Parameters or locals of type 'Utf8JsonStreamReader' cannot be declared in async methods or async lambda expressions." when trying to use it like you do in your first example. How did you get it to build like that?

Answer (score 5):

I understand this is an old post, but the recently announced `System.Text.Json support for IAsyncEnumerable` in .Net 6 Preview 4 provides solution the problem mentioned in OP.

```
private async IAsyncEnumerable<T> GetList<T>(Uri url, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    using (var httpResponse = await httpClient.GetAsync(url, cancellationToken))
    {
        using (var stream = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        {

            await foreach(var item in JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable<T>(stream))
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This would provide an on-demand deserialization and is quite useful when working with large data. Please note that at the moment the feature is limited to root level JSON arrays.

More details on the feature could be found [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-6-preview-4/)

Comment: I tried using `DeserializeAsyncEnumerable` for streaming and ran into an issue, apparently it still tries to read the whole stream before producing any data: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/63864

Comment: Same here. Is there any news?

Comment: Streaming doesn't actually work in .NET 6 as previously mentioned, but does work correctly in .NET 7 (and assuming higher).

Answer (score 0):

It feels like you need to implent your own stream reader. You have to read bytes one-by-one and stop as soon as object definition completed. It is indeed pretty low-leveled. As such you WILL NOT load entire file into RAM, but rather take the part you're dealing with. Does it seem to be an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using multiple tasks with `ChannelReader` it's possible to use the `System.IO.Pipelines` extension package along with `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` in .NET 5 (C# 9) like this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Buffers;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Pipelines;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static readonly byte[] NewLineChars = {(byte)'\r', (byte)'\n'};
    static readonly byte[] WhiteSpaceChars = {(byte)'\r', (byte)'\n', (byte)' ', (byte)'\t'};

    private static async Task Main()
    {
        JsonSerializerOptions jsonOptions = new(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web);
        var json = "{\"some\":\"thing1\"}\r\n{\"some\":\"thing2\"}\r\n{\"some\":\"thing3\"}";
        var contentStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
        var pipeReader = PipeReader.Create(contentStream);
        await foreach (var foo in ReadItemsAsync<Foo>(pipeReader, jsonOptions))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"foo: {foo.Some}");
        }
    }

    static async IAsyncEnumerable<TValue> ReadItemsAsync<TValue>(PipeReader pipeReader, JsonSerializerOptions jsonOptions = null)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var result = await pipeReader.ReadAsync();
            var buffer = result.Buffer;
            bool isCompleted = result.IsCompleted;
            SequencePosition bufferPosition = buffer.Start;
            while (true)
            {
                var(value, advanceSequence) = TryReadNextItem<TValue>(buffer, ref bufferPosition, isCompleted, jsonOptions);
                if (value != null)
                {
                    yield return value;
                }

                if (advanceSequence)
                {
                    pipeReader.AdvanceTo(bufferPosition, buffer.End); //advance our position in the pipe
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (isCompleted)
                yield break;
        }
    }

    static (TValue, bool) TryReadNextItem<TValue>(ReadOnlySequence<byte> sequence, ref SequencePosition sequencePosition, bool isCompleted, JsonSerializerOptions jsonOptions)
    {
        var reader = new SequenceReader<byte>(sequence.Slice(sequencePosition));
        while (!reader.End) // loop until we've come to the end or read an item
        {
            if (reader.TryReadToAny(out ReadOnlySpan<byte> itemBytes, NewLineChars, advancePastDelimiter: true))
            {
                sequencePosition = reader.Position;
                if (itemBytes.TrimStart(WhiteSpaceChars).IsEmpty)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                return (JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TValue>(itemBytes, jsonOptions), false);
            }
            else if (isCompleted)
            {
                // read last item
                var remainingReader = sequence.Slice(reader.Position);
                using var memoryOwner = MemoryPool<byte>.Shared.Rent((int)reader.Remaining);
                remainingReader.CopyTo(memoryOwner.Memory.Span);
                reader.Advance(remainingReader.Length); // advance reader to the end
                sequencePosition = reader.Position;
                if (!itemBytes.TrimStart(WhiteSpaceChars).IsEmpty)
                {
                    return (JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TValue>(memoryOwner.Memory.Span, jsonOptions), true);
                }
                else
                {
                    return (default, true);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // no more items in sequence
                break;
            }
        }

        // PipeReader needs to read more
        return (default, true);
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public string Some
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Run at https://dotnetfiddle.net/6j3KGg

Answer (score 0):

dotnet 8+

you can use HttpClientJsonExtensions `var data = HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsAsyncEnumerable<YourResponseType>(url)`

it will return  IAsyncEnumerable<YourResponseType?>

which can be used by iterating over the result

```
await foreach (var item in response)
{
    //use it here or return
    yield return item
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you could use `Newtonsoft.Json` serializer ?
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm

Especially see section:

> Optimize Memory Usage

**Edit**

You could try deserializing values from JsonTextReader, e.g.

```
using (var textReader = new StreamReader(stream))
using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(textReader))
{
    while (await reader.ReadAsync(cancellationToken))
    {
        yield return reader.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. This isn't about performance at all, it's about streaming access *without* loading everything in memory

Comment: Have you opened the related link or just said what you think? In the link I have sent in the section I mentioned there is a code snippet of how to deserialize JSON from stream.

Comment: Read the question again please - the OP asks how to process the elements *without* deserializing everything in memory. Not just read from a stream, but only process what comes from the stream. `I don't want them to be in memory all at once, but I would rather read and process them one by one.` The relevant class in JSON.NET is JsonTextReader.

Comment: In any case, a link-only answer isn't considered a good answer, and nothing in that link answers the OP's question. A link to JsonTextReader would be better