# Is there an equivalent for JRaw in System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-core-3.1, system.text.json

I'm migrating an ASP.NET Core 2 application to ASP.NET Core 3. My controllers need to return objects that have a property which is already a JSON string, so it looks something like this:

```cs
public class Thing {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; } // JSON Data
}

var thing = new Thing
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "Thing",
    Data = "{\"key\":\"value\"}"
};
```

`Thing` should be serialized so that the `Data` property is not a string, but part of the JSON object. Like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Thing",
    "data": {
        "key": "value"
    }
}
```

In .NET Core 2 and `Newtonsoft.Json` I used [`JRaw`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JRaw.htm) as the type for `Data`, so the serializer knew that the property is already serialized as JSON and didn't try to represent it as a string.

.NET Core 3 uses `System.Text.Json`, which is incompatible with `JRaw`. Is there an equivalent that does the same thing? I was able to use `JsonElement` as the type for `Data` and convert the string with `JsonDocument.Parse(jsonString).RootElement`. This produces the desired result, but I'd like to avoid an unnecessary deserialize+serialize step, since the data object may be relatively big.

Comment: You can still use Json.Net for the times where System.Text.Json just doesn't cut it. System.Text.Json is intentionally light on features and was introduced to remove the dependency on Json.Net - there's no reason why you can't add it back in though.

Comment: Looks like not, see [Writing raw property values when using System.Text.Json #1784](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1784) and [Proposal: Utf8JsonWriter.WriteUtf8Json #32849](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/32849)

Comment: Also, don't forget to dispose of the `JsonDocument` after you are done with it.  If you need a `JsonElement` to survive after the document is disposed, you need to clone it.

Comment: Should I make that an answer?

Comment: @dbc Go ahead. It seems that I'll have to continue using the good old Newtonsoft for now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

.NET 6 has introduced [`Utf8JsonWriter.WriteRawValue(string json, bool skipInputValidation = false)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonwriter.writerawvalue?view=net-6.0):

> Writes the input as JSON content. It is expected that the input content is a single complete JSON value. ...
>
> When writing untrusted JSON values, do not set `skipInputValidation` to `true` as this can result in invalid JSON being written, or an invalid overall payload being written to the writer instance.

Thus you can now introduce the following converters:

```
/// <summary>
/// Serializes the contents of a string value as raw JSON.  The string is validated as being an RFC 8259-compliant JSON payload
/// </summary>
public class RawJsonConverter : JsonConverter<string>
{
    public override string Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        using var doc = JsonDocument.ParseValue(ref reader);
        return doc.RootElement.GetRawText();
    }

    protected virtual bool SkipInputValidation => false;

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        // skipInputValidation : true will improve performance, but only do this if you are certain the value represents well-formed JSON!
        writer.WriteRawValue(value, skipInputValidation : SkipInputValidation);
}

/// <summary>
/// Serializes the contents of a string value as raw JSON.  The string is NOT validated as being an RFC 8259-compliant JSON payload
/// </summary>
public class UnsafeRawJsonConverter : RawJsonConverter
{
    protected override bool SkipInputValidation => true;
}
```

And apply the converter of your choice to your data model:

```
public class Thing {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(UnsafeRawJsonConverter))]
    public string Data { get; set; } // JSON Data
}
```

Notes:

- `Utf8JsonReader` does not appear to have an equivalent method to read a raw value of any type, so `JsonDocument` is still required to deserialize a raw JSON value.
- `Utf8JsonWriter.WriteRawValue(null)` and `Utf8JsonWriter.WriteRawValue("null")` generate identical JSON, namely `null`.  When deserialized, `doc.RootElement.GetRawText()` seems to return a null value for both, rather than a string containing the token `null`.
- You seem to be concerned about performance, so I applied `UnsafeRawJsonConverter` to your data model.  However, you should only use this converter if you are certain that `Data` contains well-formed JSON.  If not, use `RawJsonConverter`:

  ```
   [JsonConverter(typeof(RawJsonConverter))]
   public string Data { get; set; } // JSON Data
  ```
- In .NET 5 and earlier `WriteRawValue()` does not exist, so you will have to parse the incoming string to a `JsonDocument` and write that:

  ```
   public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   {
       using var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(value);
       doc.WriteTo(writer);
   }
  ```

  This of course checks that `value` is well-formed; there is no ability to write raw JSON and skip input validation in earlier releases.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MBVYoB).

Comment: are you aware if there's an equivalent for .net5? or some kind of workaround?

Comment: @R.L - I believe in .NET 5 you must load your raw JSON into a `JsonDocument` and do [`JsonDocument.WriteTo(Utf8JsonWriter)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument.writeto?view=net-6.0).

Comment: @R.L - Or I suppose you could try to write code to manually stream from a `Utf8JsonReader` to a `Utf8JsonWriter` like the one shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55429664/3744182) by [mtosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7217527/mtosh) to [Parsing a JSON file with .NET core 3.0/System.text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54983533/3744182) but that seems really involved.