# How can I serialize a literal JSON value with System.Text.Json?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, system.text.json

I have a class in C# 6, something like the following:

```
public class Foo {
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string OtherStuff { get; set; }
}
```

The `OtherStuff` property is a known-valid JSON-encoded string.

I'm trying to return this class from an API method, using the default `System.Text.Json` serializer. But I want `OtherStuff` to be written out *literally*, not escaped into a string value.

Things I've tried:

- Looked in `JsonSerializerOptions` for something to do this.
- Tried using `System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonNode` instead of `string`. It still emits the value as a string.
- Tried writing a custom `JsonConverter`, but the `Write()` method takes in `Utf8JsonWriter`, which does not appear to have a way to write a string *as a literal value*, only ways to write a string as a JSON string.

```
public class LiteralJsonConverter : JsonConverter<string> {
  public override string Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, 
                              Type typeToConvert, 
                              JsonSerializerOptions options)
       => reader.GetString();

  public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, 
                             string value, 
                             JsonSerializerOptions options)
      => writer.WriteStringValue(value); // Can't find a method to
                                         // write a pre-encoded value
}
```

I want to avoid having to parse this string from JSON into an object just so I can re-emit it in JSON. It's a JSON string in my database, and the data model is opaque to the API.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Side note for anyone looking: in Json.Net you can use `[JsonProperty(Type = typeof(JRaw)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.Text.Json` supports this starting from version 6, the method is called [WriteRawValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonwriter.writerawvalue?view=net-6.0):

```cs
public class LiteralJsonConverter : JsonConverter<string>
{
  public override string Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, 
                              Type typeToConvert, 
                              JsonSerializerOptions options)
                              => reader.GetString();

  public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, 
                             string value, 
                             JsonSerializerOptions options) 
                             => writer.WriteRawValue(value);        
}
```

If you are on .NET 6 then it's available by default. Otherwise you can install nuget package `System.Text.Json` of version 6 to get access to this functionality (this package supports .NET Standard so can be used even in old .NET 4).

Note that it accepts second parameter: `skipInputValidation`, so for even more perfomance, if you are sure what you are writing is valid json - you can skip that and use `WriteRawValue(value, true)`.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! I have no idea how I missed that in the method list. I must've looked at it 20 times.

Comment: This works perfectly for writing but `reader.GetString();` will only read a JSON value which is actually a string primitive.  To read an arbitrary JSON value of any type then return it as a string I think you need to load it into a `JsonDocument` and return the raw text (being sure to dispose the `JsonDocument`).  See e.g. [Is there an equivalent for JRaw in System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70477321/3744182).