# Avoid re-serializing of a json string

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, system.text.json

Is there a way to selectively exclude a field from re-serialization, if it already contains a valid json string?

Here is what I am attempting.

First, I define a class of the result row I recieve from my database.

```
public class objectToSerialize
{
    public string identifier { get; set; }
    public string jsonPayload { get; set; }

    public objectToSerialize()
    {
        identifier = String.Empty;
        jsonPayload = String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Then I run my query and add all the results to a list.

```
List<objectToSerialize> listOfobjectToSerialize = new List<objectToSerialize>();
[...]

while(SqlDataReader.Read())
{
   [...]
   listOfobjectToSerialize.add(objectToSerialize)
}
```

Finally, I return my list as an [APS.NET OkObjectResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.okobjectresult?view=aspnetcore-3.1), which serializes the list to JSON by default.

```
[...]
return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(listOfobjectToSerialize);
```

The `jsonPayload` already contains a json string, that should not be re-serialized again when returning the result.
So far I have deserialized the `jsonPayload` to an object, which was then serialized fine, but I would like to avoid that unnessesary step.
I have tried using the field attributes `[JsonIgnore]` and `[NonSerialized()]` but they remove the field from the result altogether.

Is there a way to include the `jsonPayload` string as-is?

Here is an example:

```
objectToSerialize.identifier = 123;
objectToSerialize.jsonPayload = @"
   {
      "ThisIsAKey" : "ThisIsAValue"
   }"
```

Desired output:

```
{
   "identifier" : 123,
   "jsonPayload" : {
      "ThisIsAKey" : "ThisIsAValue"
   }
}
```

Actual output:

```
{
   "identifier" : 123,
   "jsonPayload" : "{
      \"ThisIsAKey\" : \"ThisIsAValue\"
   }"
}
```

So far I am trying to write my own [custom JsonConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1).

Comment: I don't think `jsonPayload` property is getting re-serialized. What makes you believe that's it's getting re-serialized?

Comment: Could you please provide a sample API response which shows this `string` re-serialization issue?

Comment: It doesnt' matter that will serialized again, it will return back after deserialization. You can add some code to exclude it but after this  it will be not valid after deserialization. Better to leave as it is.

Comment: Hi, I Added an example, also I started an attempt to handle this with a custom JsonConverter. But I am unsure If I will succeed.

Comment: in .NET 6 and later you can use a custom `JsonConverter<string>` and call `Utf8JsonWriter.WriteRawValue()` to write a JSON string as-is.  See [Is there an equivalent for JRaw in System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70477321/3744182) and [How can I serialize a literal JSON value with System.Text.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69929260/3744182).  In fact these look to be duplicates, agree?

Answer (score 0):

this will not be even compiled

```
objectToSerialize.jsonPayload = @"
   {
      "ThisIsAKey" : "ThisIsAValue"
   }"
```

if you want Desired output

```
objectToSerialize.jsonPayload = new
   {
      ThisIsAKey = "ThisIsAValue"
   };
```

but as I guess your jsonPayload is a string , so you can only do this

```
objectToSerialize.jsonPayload = @"{
      ""ThisIsAKey"" : ""ThisIsAValue"" 
      }";
```

leave like this, otherwise you are just looking for a trouble, you will not be able to deserialize jsonPayload to string when you get your response.

Comment: I see, I was motivated to find a better way than first using Newtonsoft JsonConvert.DeserializeObject() to deserialize the string to an object, then serialize it again when I deliver the OkObjectResult. This seemed unnecessarily inefficient, but for now, I cannot see a better solution. Thank s

Answer (score 0):

If it is already the JSON, we could give a try to plain/text as the content type of the response.

May be,

Request.Content = "text/plain";

return Content(alreadyCreatedJson);