# How to return JSON string as an sub-object in a .NET 6 WebApi controller?

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, .net-6.0, system.text.json

I have the following data structure which I want to return as result from a controller:

```
public class DataModel
{
    public string Id { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public string Description { get; private set; }

    public string ProjectId { get; private set; }

    public string Content { get; private set; }

    public DateTime CreationTime { get; private set; }

    public DateTime? LastModificationTime { get; private set; }
}
```

What I get in Swagger is:

```
{
  "id": "642af19d6d5bb761f5a62cc0",
  "name": "Test submission 8",
  "description": "test description",
  "projectId": "1a1b1c",
  "content": "{ \"Name\" : \"Test 1\", \"Id\" : \"id1\", \"Value\" : 1 }",
  "creationTime": "2023-04-03T15:32:45Z",
  "lastModificationTime": null
}
```

What I would like to get instead is:

```
{
  "id": "642af19d6d5bb761f5a62cc0",
  "name": "Test submission 8",
  "description": "test description",
  "projectId": "1a1b1c",
  "content": {
    "Name": "Test 1",
    "Id": "id1",
    "Value": 1
  },
  "creationTime": "2023-04-03T15:32:45Z",
  "lastModificationTime": null
}
```

Content is a JSON string. I can't  create a specific kind of class and deserialize the JSON to that because the structure of the string can vary.

How can I modify the object and type of Content so Content looks like an sub-object in the JSON returned by the controller?

Comment: Given you say you cannot create a `Content` class then effectively say you want a `Content` class I believe it would help you to sort out if you just need to parse that first example OR create the class for the "I want this" example.

Comment: As Henry Ford said: "You can have any color Model T you want as long as it is black" or something to that effect

Comment: You could apply `RawJsonConverter` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70477321/3744182) to [Is there an equivalent for JRaw in System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60931870/3744182) to `Content`.

Comment: "How can I modify the object and type of Content so Content looks like an sub-object" What in exact terms, without vagueness. are you calling "sub-object", can you show the example pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return some object that will be correctly serialized. For example you can use the [`JsonNode` API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/use-dom-utf8jsonreader-utf8jsonwriter?pivots=dotnet-6-0#use-jsonnode) introduced in C# 6:

```cs
public class DataModel
{
    // ....

    // sample value and public setter for testing purposes:
    public JsonNode Content { get; set; } = JsonNode.Parse("""{ "Name" : "Test 1", "Id" : "id1", "Value" : 1 }""");

}
```

Another option is to create a special wrapper with [custom converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0) which will write string as is (though in this case you either need to validate the string in converter or you can get an invalid JSON).