# Find stream positions of JSON fragments

Tags: .net, json, json.net, system.text.json, .net-4.8

I am trying to find stream start and stop positions of JSON fragments.

At the moment I am using `JsonTextReader` which allows me to use the `JsonTextReader.Path` property which can be checked using a regex for matching. It does have `LinePosition` and `LineNumber` properties but these are of course for line-based character positions and not the byte stream positions.

The idea is to have fast lookup of JSON fragments using stream seeking (in practice using a substream that sees a slice of another stream, that's why I need the fragment start and stop positions in the underlying stream).

I have also tried `System.Text.Json.JsonDocument` which has a great API but unfortunateky reads all bytes into memory.

When fragments are looked up they are mapped into domain objects using `System.Text.Json` where memory consumption is less of an issue since its just fragments.

It is not directly possible to use JsonSerializer to deserialize the fragments, since custom fragment parsing/object-mapping happens using System.Text.Json.

Also, on .NET Framework 4.8, not .NET Core.

Comment: Json.NET doesn't report `Stream` positions because it doesn't work with streams or byte sequences, it works with `TextReader` and character sequences.  Since `StreamReader` doesn't report the encoding mapping from `Stream` position to character index, neither does Json.NET.

Comment: If you're willing to switch to [tag:system.text.json] then `Utf8JsonReader` works directly with utf8 byte sequences and does report positioning via [`Utf8JsonReader.TokenStartIndex`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonreader.tokenstartindex?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Json_Utf8JsonReader_TokenStartIndex).  `Utf8JsonStreamReader` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55429664/3744182) to [Parsing a JSON file with .NET core 3.0/System.text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54983533/3744182) is built on `Utf8JsonReader`, might that work for you?