# How can I use the Utf8JsonReader to read from a StreamReader

Tags: c#, json, .net, system.text.json

The [Utf8JsonReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonreader?view=net-7.0) has constructors to read from:

- `ReadOnlySpan<byte> jsonData`
- `ReadOnlySequence<byte> jsonData`

So what would be the best approach to read from a traditional `StreamReader`?

Comment: The premise of your question doesn't make sense. In essense, `Utf8JsonReader` already IS a reader, so passing it another reader is redundant. You can use the `JsonSerializer.Deserialize(Stream)` overloads instead, but again, those take the raw Stream source, not an instance of a reader wrapping the stream.

Comment: There is an [open feature request](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27156) for this to be added to the dotnet runtime. In the comments, AArnot has linked to [his own implementation](https://github.com/AArnott/Nerdbank.Streams/blob/main/doc/AsStream.md#readonlysequencebyte) as a reference

Comment: @DavidL there are cases where you use two third-party libraries, one of which produces only `StreamReader` as output and another which only accepts `ReadOnlySequence<byte>` as input. In that case, you have to convert between the two. I've written code to do this myself in the past, but it would be nice to have native support

Comment: What are you going to do with the `Utf8JsonReader` after you construct it?  You may have somewhat of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here, `Utf8JsonReader` is quite low level.  If you can tell us what you are trying to do we might be able to suggest an alternative using a higher-level API.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson I understand your point, but even in that case, what you are fundamentally wanting to do is convert the underlying _stream_ to a `ReadOnlySequence<byte>`, which makes perfect sense to me. It is more about abstracting the stream from the `StreamReader` and converting it to `ReadOnlySequence` and yes, native support would be wonderful.

Comment: @DavidL I just want to port this code from Newtonsoft to System.Text.Json: https://github.com/danipen/TextMateSharp/blob/master/src/TextMateSharp/Internal/Parser/Json/JSONPListParser.cs

Comment: @DanielPeñalba - the code at that link doesn't just construct a JSON reader from a `StreamReader`.  It manually streams through the JSON and parses each token.  System.Text.Json does not support that easily out of the box.  But maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55429664/3744182) by mtosh to [Parsing a JSON file with .NET core 3.0/System.text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54983533/3744182) does what you need.