# How can I efficiently handle large JSON data in C#?

Tags: c#, json, performance, optimization, large-data

I'm working on a project where I need to process and manipulate large JSON datasets in C#. However, I'm facing performance issues when working with files that contain thousands of records. What are some best practices and libraries that I can use to efficiently handle large JSON data in C#? Are there any optimizations or techniques I should be aware of to improve the processing speed and memory usage when working with large JSON files?

Comment: For large JSON datasets, I would stream the file and use the data as it is streamed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747477/how-to-parse-huge-json-file-as-stream-in-json-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You face issues because you parse lots of data and store them in memory even when you use them only once (or transform into something else). Depending on the input data and processing, you can use two approaches here.

The first is to stream data from I(Async)Enumerable. It requires the root document to be an array. It's the easiest way to handle large data. An example:

```
await foreach(var entry in JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable<Entry>(stream))
{
    // process each entry.
}
```

The second is to utilize Utf8JsonReader. An simple example:

```
Utf8JsonReader reader = new(data);

if (!reader.Read() || reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartArray)
    throw new JsonException();

while (reader.Read())
{
    if(reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndArray)
    {
        break;
    }

    if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartObject)
        throw new JsonException();

    var entry = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Entry>(ref reader) ?? 
        throw new JsonException();

    //process entry
}
```

Keep in mind that working with Utf8JsonReader is more complicated because it doesn't support reading from Stream directly. It may not be a problem if the input data you're processing may be loaded in memory (i.e., may be expressed with ReadOnlySpan<byte> like byte[]), but if its size is, let's say, bigger than 4 GB, you'd have to implement parsing and handle EOFs by yourself because storing such a large string is another problem. [Utf8JsonReader usage guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/use-utf8jsonreader)

I usually use System.Text.Json, but Newtonsoft.Json is able to do this as well.

In general, there is no specific technique to reduce pressure on memory or CPU to keep in mind, because libraries are already good enough for this.