# Removing HTML Tags using XmlDocument in C# 4.0

Tags: c#-4.0, xmldocument

I have below code where I am trying to delete all the html element which are passed.

```
String inputString = "<img class="imgRight" title="Zürich, Switzerland" src="test.png" alt="Switzerland" width="44" height="44"/>
<p class="first">Zurich</p>
<p class="second">Test</p>
<p class="first">Testing</p>
<img class="imgRight" title="Zürich, Switzerland" src="1.png" alt="Switzerland" width="44" height="44"/>
<a href="test.aspx">Hello</a>"; //Sample HTML String

String[] htmlTags = new String[] { "a", "img", "link:ComponentLink" };

String removedTagsHtml = RemoveHTMLTags(inputString,htmlTags);//Giving error "There are multiple root elements." 

public static string RemoveHTMLTags(String inputString, String[] htmlTags)
{
    String strResult = String.Empty;
    foreach (String htmlTag in htmlTags)
    {                
        XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.LoadXml(inputString);
        XmlNamespaceManager xMan = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.NameTable);
        xMan.AddNamespace("xs", xDoc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);

        XmlNode xNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("xs:" + htmlTag + "", xMan);
        xDoc.RemoveAll();
        xDoc.AppendChild(xNode);
        string seeOutputHere = xDoc.OuterXml;

    }
    return strResult;
}
```

Function generates error "There are multiple root elements."

Answer (score 0):

Even if you fix the "multiple root elements" thing (see [LINQ to XML - Load XML fragments from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374426/linq-to-xml-load-xml-fragments-from-file) for one example), general-case HTML is still not a valid XML.

For HTML processing, you should look into HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack will be last attempt if I fail to get the required results, any idea how to fix above problem

Comment: See my link to another question that describes how to load a set of `XElement` from multi-root string.