# Cannot load SQL Column Set into XDocument via SqlXml

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

We have a data table that uses sparse columns, and a [column set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280521(v=sql.110).aspx). When we query data from this table, we are only bringing back a couple of key columns plus the columnset column.

The columnset column is returned as an `SqlXml` field type, and I want to parse through the XML to convert it to a dictionary. But, the XML data doesn't seem to be well formed; as whenever I try this:

```
var columnSet = rdr.GetSqlXml(rdr.GetOrdinal("ColSet"));
if (!columnSet.IsNull)
{
    var xml = XDocument.Load(xmlData.CreateReader());
```

it throws an exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: This operation would create an incorrectly structured document.
  at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.ValidateDocument(XNode previous, XmlNodeType allowBefore, XmlNodeType allowAfter)
  at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.ValidateNode(XNode node, XNode previous)\r\n   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.AddNodeSkipNotify(XNode n)
  at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r)
  at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r, LoadOptions o)
  at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)   
  at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
```

If I use `GetString()` instead of `GetSqlXml()`, I definitely get back invalid XML -- it has no root element, and I have to perform string manipulation to get it to load into an `XDocument`.

Is there some way to get the `SqlXml` value for a columnset to produce a valid XML document?

Comment: It is simple to just add "<Root>" + GetString() + "</Root>"

Comment: Yes as I said in my question, that's what I'm doing now. But since I *want* the XML as XML, it seems silly to have the DataReader construct an XmlReader to convert the XML to string to turn around and convert back to XML for parsing.

Comment: No datareader : XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<Root>" + GetString() + "</Root>");

Comment: GetString *makes* an XmlReader internally, that's my point.

Comment: Try here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042902/xml-error-there-are-multiple-root-elements  or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374426/linq-to-xml-load-xml-fragments-from-file

Comment: That second one actually gets pretty close to what I need. Though, at this point I realized it would probably be just as easy to navigate the XML using the `XmlReader` itself.