# Why does `XmlDocument.LoadXml()` not work with namespace?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml

I have an XML tag written as string:

```
<w:sym w:font="Wingdings" w:char="F0FE"/>
```

I would like to create an XML tag from the string without using explicit methods like `AddAttribute()` etc. So I use `XmlDocument.LoadXml()`, like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("w", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");
doc.LoadXml(@"<w:sym w:font=""Wingdings"" w:char=""F0FE""/>");
```

`LoadXml()` is throwing an exception saying that the prefix "w" is not defined.

This is surprising to me as I define the namespace with `NameTable`.

What is the problem here?

---

**Edit**: I have seen a lot of answers explaining how to read fragments, but I have not found one that explained what to do with a namespace.

Comment: Namespace prefixes only ever have *local* meanings. Just because in the "outer" context of your C# code you've identified a namespace and used a `w` prefix for it, that has no relationship to any `w` prefix assigned *within* the document that you're trying to load.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, thank you for your explanation. One can assume the `.NameTable` of an `XmlDocument` to be a reliable reference to look up namespaces in any situation, while parsing XML. This turns out wrong, as you explain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ to XML - Load XML fragments from file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374426/linq-to-xml-load-xml-fragments-from-file)

Answer (score 0):

Here is not an explanation why it does not work with `.NameTable`, but a workaround how to achieve the goal.

Wrap your tag inside another tag and define the workspace there, like this:

```
String fullTagToRead = 
  @"<document xmlns:w=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"">" 
+ @"<w:sym w:font=""Wingdings"" w:char=""F0FE""/>" 
+ @"</document>")
```

Like this, `LoadXml()` works like a charm. It is not even necessary to write the XML declaration tag.

Comment: `LoadXML` is meant to read entire XML documents while you have a fragment. This *does* fix the invalid fragment. There are multiple duplicates that show how to read fragments through an XmlReader by setting its conformange level to fragment